# Data is not loading after calling a function synchronously in react hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to open a component as a popup in edit Mode (for editing the data). I have created a function using async await. I am first calling the API & then setting a state for component to be open in edit mode and then setting state for a component to be open as popup.

My function code is -

```
async function getAPIData(key: string): Promise<void> {
        try {
            await getAPIAction("A", "B", "C", key); // API call
            await setFormMode("EDIT"); // setting popup to be open in edit mode
        }
        finally {
            setPopupOpen(true); // makes popup to be open
        }
    };
```

Everything is working fine. API is being called & popup is also getting opened but I am not getting the editable data on popup component. If I am writing `setTimeout(() => {setPopupOpen(true);},1000)` in `finally` block then Popup component is loaded with data otherwise Popup component is loaded without data.

What am I doing wrong ? I want my popup to be loaded with data.

Comment: Just something you can try. Make sure when you set data in the form/popup its part of the Dom. I mean what might be happening is the data is getting set after the render cycle and when you set data the rendering is not happening again.

Comment: Does `getAPIAction` actually return a promise? It looks like the popup will only show the data if the data is available before the popup is shown. The fact that it works with `setTimeout` suggests that the popup is shown before the data is loaded. However, even in that case I would expect the popup to update as soon as the data is available. There are too many unknowns to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: Next question after Felix's is `setFormMode` is `useState` returned value, do not use await before `setFormMode`

Comment: @Ramesh Yes I tried removing await but still it's not working.

Comment: @Manish Yes you are right. How can I get it done ?

Comment: is `getAPIData` called from `useEffect`?

Comment: @Ramesh No I am calling `getAPIData`  inside a function.

Comment: Can you post place around `PopupOpen` ? Please remember React do not encourage you to do direct DOM manipulation

Comment: And the call happens in response to an event?